# How to cut and print the first word from different hostnames?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, unix

Our linux servers hostrnames like abc.ind.com, abc.indii.hyd.com ,apt.bind.com 
now we want to print the first name and need to cut the after (.)  words
after cutting the hosts(abc.ind.com,abc.indii.hyd.com,apt.bind.com) 
expected output is abc abc apt

### how to do it using single command in linux?

Comment: There are a million ways to remove everything including and after the first period in bash. What have you tried? Also, it's not clear what your input file (or some other form of input) looks like, from above.

Comment: my basic requiremnet is cut any word after first . in my hostnames.    eg:abc.xx.x.x.x want to cut(.xx.x.x.x) and need output is abc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 
hostname=(abc.ind.com abc.indii.hyd.com apt.bind.com) #you can specify file also code will change little bit

for name in ${hostname[@]}

do

name=`echo $name | cut -f1 -d "."`

echo $name

done